# Apache Cordova portrait orientation forcing not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, phonegap, apache-cordova

In a Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova application, I went to the config.xml file and set Orientation = "Portrait". When I see the result in all Android emulators, and in a real device, this setting has no effect,  because if I turn the device the layout of the page is completely destroyed.

I searched a lot for this issue but couldn't find any solution. Do I have to spend hours and hours to manage the layout when the phone is in landscape mode?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, could you please try remove the platform and rebuild again?

Comment: @ Elvis Xia - MSFT I removed the android platform and then readded it, but now when I build the solution I have the error "TypeError: undefined is not a function", googled a little and tried something but of course it did not solve anything.

Comment: @ Elvis Xia - MSFT  I tried with a new Apache Cordova project, set the 
orientation preference to "portrait" in config.xml, when I launch the  Ripple emulators and I switch to landscape mode, it adapts the screen content (even if the screen has rotated, the Cordova logo is still vertical). Is this what you did when trying to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I launch the Ripple emulators and I switch to landscape mode, it adapts the screen content.

That's where the problem is. Ripple doesn't provide a complete simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities (plugins).

Please refer to [Cautions of Run your Apache Cordova app on the Apache Ripple simulator](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/).

So please try that on real device or an emulator. I tried it on emulator and it works fine.

Comment: @ Elvis Xia - MSFT  when I try with a real device, Cordova isn't able to detect the device (even if I can deploy to the device when using the Phonegap desktop application, but in this case the "Orientation" value="portrait" preference does not work). But with the kitkat emulators in Visual Studio it works. Thank you!